# Closing "In what sense do Presbyterians consider Christ's sacrifice “perfect”?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

[In what sense do Presbyterians consider Christ's sacrifice “perfect”?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/60224/6071)

I do not think this question should have been reopened. It is still far too muddled.

The main question, with the two options, is clear enough. What is the Presbyterian view of sanctification? Great question.

But the title, and other parts of it, introduce a great many other ideas, and I can't see how they can be brought together into one cohesive whole:

- the idea of Christ's sacrifice being perfect/fully sufficient
- forfeiting salvation
- the (potential) misrepresentation of Catholic doctrine by Reformed people

I have already voted to close this question as unclear, before it was reopened single-handedly by a mod. As I cannot vote to close again I am posting here to request others to close it now.

---

A comment from another who seem to agree:

> Your question is a bit awkward even if you change the Presbyterian position to be more accurate, because the title and two questions inside the question are all different questions, so you're asking three questions in one. You should split them up into new questions, e.g. "In what sense do prezzies consider Christ's sacrifice perfect?", "What is the Biblical basis for the Presbyterian view on sanctification", and "How do Presbyterians consider their view on sanctification to be more correct than the Catholic view?" or words to that effect. - [Birdie](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60224/in-what-sense-do-presbyterians-consider-christs-sacrifice-perfect#comment163799_60224)